# Android Cursorloader to playlist

Tags: android, mediastore, android-cursorloader

I have music player app, I am querying `Mediastore` database using `content provider`, when a user clicks on song entry, I create an object from cursor of that song and pass it to service which controls the playback

Now if I want to queue remaining songs I have to create object of all the entries from database and pass it to service, but what if I have **N** number of songs.

So my question is, whether the above approach is correct? and what is the best to way for such scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more approach,

Make a database and put all songs with an id(like 0,1,2),path,AlbumName..,etc, with the help of Mediastore. Then use that database to fetch data. When user click a song just pass the id, and in the screen where you want to play the song, use the id to get details from Database and to play the song.

Comment: There is one drawback of this approach, suppose I have three screen say  all songs, albums, artist. Initially user selects clicks a song from all songs and rest of the songs are put in db, now user moves to albums and clicks on a song, so now we have to show user a choice to play this song,enqueue it, or play next. if user selects play next the ids above will become useless